# Referncing a .dll file which was written in ASP and Vb INTO a .NET 4.0 Project with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, com, vbscript

I am trying to reference an old .dll file which was written in classic asp with VB. I am now trying to reference it to a C# asp.NET 4.0 Application but I am recieving that error. Is this possible?

[image: Error Recieved]

Comment: There is no such thing as a .dll file written in ASP. ASP is entirely script-based. You may have a dll containing COM components written in VB6.

Answer (score 2):

As the error said, that dll isnt com or net based assembly. So you have to load it at run time by using DLLImport apis

Comment: Thanks let me experiment with it now